# how to deal with users who have locked their desktop while resetting password with must change password on next logon bit ON

Tags: active-directory

If a user has locked his desktop, and asks for reset password.
If mustchangepassword is enabled, the user cannot unlock his computer.
This is the error message he gets:
'Your password has expired. Please change your password at another machine and retry or contact your domain administrator'

Any way to work around this?

---

My apologies for not framing the question in a clearer manner.

The issue is that I am remotely reseting passwords for users. When resetting the password, I want to make them change it the next time they login.
To make them change password, I set attribute 'pwdLastSet' to zero.

For a user who locked his desktop(part of a domain), this approach leads to error I mentioned earlier:
'Your password has expired. Please change your password at another machine and retry or contact your domain administrator'

It is working well for a user who is logging in afresh.

Comment: belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Is there any reason why the quoted instructions can't be followed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to deal with users who have locked their desktop while resetting password with must change password on next logon bit ON](http://serverfault.com/questions/308280/how-to-deal-with-users-who-have-locked-their-desktop-while-resetting-password-wit)

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify: Is the user unable to use another PC?

You could: Get the domain admin to reset the password, wait a few minutes for the change to propigate to the PC then unlock the PC.
If that doesn't work, logon to the locked PC with an admin account and either: change the password using the `User Manager` or reboot the PC. Upon reboot use the new password that the admin created at the server or at the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Go to another machine on the domain, log in, change password, log off. Wait two minutes. Log into locked machine.

If it's an emergency, shut down the laptop, on restart, change password. Run chkdsk on system drive at next reboot, since you probably shouldn't have forced a shutdown on the system in the first place.

...that's really all there is to it. Log in to another workstation for a few minutes. Or don't reset the user's password while they're logged in, or train users to change their passwords when the "your password will expire in X days" starts showing up.